# How to customize Jquery-timepicker list?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using jquery-timepicker.I want to customize that time list, i want add my custom list in timepicker time list.Is it possible or do you have any idea in which timepicker i can do that customization ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: read plugin documentations

Comment: I read it but there is nothing related to my work